# Flutter Programmable Timer

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to build wedding app for my school project. I can't build a programmable timer. Users should set the timer like "10 week later" and timer start to countdown to 9 week, 23 hours, etc. Any Suggestions on how to achieve my target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps that you should follow to complete this assignment:

1. You have to let user choose a date and/or a time.
2. You have to calculate the remaining String (x years, x months, x days, etc..)
3. Show it to the user.
4. Begin a timer, that will update the UI.

```dart
//Timer

Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  //every 1 second, the state will be updated
  setState(() {});
});

//remainingTime calculator
//you have to put this string to a Text widget
String get  _calculateRemainingTime{
    Duration remainingDuration = widget.date.difference(DateTime.now());

    if(remainingDuration.inSeconds <= 0){
      return 'Time has come';
    }

    int remainingSeconds = remainingDuration.inSeconds % 60;

    int remainingMinutes = remainingDuration.inMinutes % 60;

    int remainingHours = remainingDuration.inHours % 24;

    int remainingDays = remainingDuration.inDays;

    int remainingMonths = remainingDays ~/ 30;

    int remainingYears = remainingMonths ~/ 12;

    remainingDays = remainingDays % 30;

    remainingMonths = remainingMonths % 12;


    return '${remainingYears != 0 ? remainingYears.toString() + ' years' : ''} ${remainingMonths != 0 ? remainingMonths.toString() + ' months' : ''} ${remainingDays != 0 ? remainingDays.toString() + ' days' : ''} ${remainingHours != 0 ? remainingHours.toString() + ' hours' : ''} ${remainingMinutes != 0 ? remainingMinutes.toString() + ' minutes' : ''} ${remainingSeconds != 0 ? remainingSeconds.toString() + ' seconds' : ''}';
  }
```

I have an example on my github page: [Flutter Timer Example](https://github.com/Prosa/Flutter-Timer-Example)

if you need further help, tell me.